# How do I view the transaction status in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using Geth v1.7 and send a transaction. How can I view the status of this transaction in the tx pool? I remember there has related command in Geth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this command: 
   txpool.status